# Jenkins - Source code analyser to validate a terraform file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, form-data, sca

I have an url that’s all about source code analyser api. I want that url to validate the terraform file and give the output.

The same url is used in postman form data and looks good. I am not sure how to achieve this in jenkins as I have to have a job for this in jenkins.

Kindly help.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a `.tf` file as a POST request to a URL with data (which is what I'm understanding you did with postman and want to replicate in Jenkins), you need to use the [httprequest plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/).

Here is an example of what your POST request might look like (assuming you are sending a file called `file.tf`:

```
httpRequest acceptType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', contentType: 'APPLICATION_OCTETSTREAM,
            httpMode: 'POST', quiet: true,
            uploadFile: 'file.tf', 
            multipartName: 'file.tf', 
            wrapAsMultipart: false,
            url: 'https://<your_url>'
```

**EDIT:**

The above plugin is meant for use with declarative pipeline. You can have the .tf file anywhere, but you need to follow a guide to setting up the declarative pipeline properly. Once you have done that, you can have the above code block within a stage pointing at where you placed your .tf file:

```
stage('send-file') {
  steps {
    dir('/path/to/tf') {
      httpRequest acceptType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', contentType: 'APPLICATION_OCTETSTREAM,
            httpMode: 'POST', quiet: true,
            uploadFile: 'file.tf', 
            multipartName: 'file.tf', 
            wrapAsMultipart: false,
            url: 'https://<your_url>'
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to use a freestyle project instead, you will have to set it up and in a "Execute Bash/Batch job" segment, use curl:

```
curl -i -X POST 'https://<your_url>' \
  -H "Content-Type: text/xml" \
  --data-binary "@path/to/tf/file"
```

Comment: @M B Can u please help with the steps to achieve this? Should it be done via freestyle project? Where should I save the file.tf please?